# How can I place text over image without damaging the original arrangement?

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=17

This is my code HTML:

```
    <div class="row sss">
        <div class="row">
    <div id="small-img" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 center">
      <ul class="lista-imagini" style="text-align:center;">
        <li class="ion"><img  src="wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/b1.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Responsive image"/><p class="qqq" style="color:white;">asdasdsa</p></li>


...//some code

</ul>
</div>
```

I want to put text over pictures (text is .qqq) but the image is (.ion)

I tried this solution but unfortunately spoil photos arrangement. Photos only keeps the place.

```
   .ion { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

.qqq { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

After I added the above code, the site looks like.

http://i61.tinypic.com/531a4p.jpg

How can I make pictures to be aligned just after you add these codes?
Can you help me please to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using `:before`. for the image which u have and place the text in the `content` of the CSS.

Comment: can you please give me an example in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work fine

```
li.ion {
  position: relative;
}

.qqq {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -19px;
}
```

Comment: had added "li" had before ... but why do this? can you please explain a little?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem for me with your code.

[image]